# I am trying to order the array by most valued, from lowest to highest, but those with 0 value are ordered after the highest valued,

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to order the array by most valued, from lowest to highest, but those with 0 rating are ordered after the highest valued, and then from highest to lowest by price

```
const product = [
  {mostValued:5, price: 5},
  {mostValued:0, price: 14},
  {mostValued:0, price: 58},
  {mostValued:3, price: 33},
  {mostValued:0, price: 25},
  {mostValued:4, price: 47},
]
 // code
product.sort((a, b) =>
      a.mostValued == b.mostValued 
        ? b.price - a.price
        : a.mostValued - b.mostValued
);
```

Those with 0 stars should be sorted after, highest to lowest by price, so the expected output would be

```
[
  {mostValued:3, price: 33},
  {mostValued:4, price: 47},
  {mostValued:5, price: 5},
  {mostValued:0, price: 58},
  {mostValued:0, price: 25},
  {mostValued:0, price: 14}
];
```

Comment: If I [take your code and execute it in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anied/um8stjn2/) it sorts as you are expecting; can you [create a runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/6831341) that actually reproduces the issue?  Unless your wording is unclear, and having the zeroes at the end of the sorted array is the _desired_ result?

Comment: @AlexanderNied That's how I understood it, yes - BsbRasd please roll back my edit if that was not your intention

Comment: Do the items with matching, non-zero `mostValued` need to be sorted by ascending price while those with zero `mostValued` are sorted by descending price? It's not clear. What would the expected output be if the list included `{mostValued:3, price: 1}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to coalesce `0`s (and other falsy values?) to `Infinity`:

```
product.sort((a, b) =>
    (a.mostValued || Infinity) - (b.mostValued || Infinity) ||
    b.price - a.price
);
```

Alternatively, specifically give those with `mostValued == 0` a priority:

```
product.sort((a, b) =>
    (a.mostValued == 0) - (b.mostValued == 0) ||
    a.mostValued - b.mostValued ||
    b.price - a.price
);
```

Comment: thank you very much, the code works but can you please explain me a little how you have done it, with infinity and the other way too,